# ConcurrentHashMap Documentation clarification

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, concurrency, synchronization

ConcurrentHashMap is fully interoperable with Hashtable in programs that rely on its thread safety but not on its synchronization details.

I am confused with Thread Safety vs Synchronization details, can any one tell me an example?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Hashtable` has every method `synchronized`, and it's a publicly available information. For example, you can inherit from `Hashtable`, add more `synchronized` methods—and know you're doing mostly OK as you use the same *synchronisation mechanism.*

Moreover, your code can use `synchronized (myHashTable)` block, effectively ensuring no `myHashTable` methods are called from other threads while you're in this block.

That's all *"synchronization details"* which are available to you and which you are free (while discouraged) to use.

Not so with `ConcurrentHashMap`: it's as thread safe (and even more so in some sense, see e.g. the answer by Peter Lawrey) as `Hashtable`, but you're not told *how* this thread safety is achieved. As a result, you cannot abuse or extend it as you like: you're supposed to use it as it is.

Answer (score 2):

A common thread safety got-cha is that the Iterator returned by `iterator()` method for the keySet(), entrySet() or values() are not thread safe for Hashtable, Vector, Collection.synchronizedXxxx(collection). While the method itself is thread safe, as soon as it returns an Iterator it could be invalid.

ConcurrentHashMap doesn't have this problem as its provides weak consistency. i.e. anything added, removed while Iterating may or may not be seen but otherwise entries appear as expect.

Answer (score 0):

`ConcurrentHashMap` allows concurrent modification of the Map from several threads without the need to block them.

Have a look on tutorial on [Synchronization and thread safety](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/thread_safety.shtml)

Comment: Just a Quick Question, if it allows modification by multiple threads then how is it thread safe?

Comment: @flash do you need a definition or a mechanics? :) If a definition, then it's "even if you change it from multiple threads concurrently, the inner structures won't be broken" (which is not the case with, e.g.,`HashMap`). If it's about mechanism (the *how*), you'll need to read the code: in brief, the technique is called *lock slicing.* Unfortunately, there's much more than that, and it won't fit into a comment.